# PHP - replace all special characters to correct display

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

I have textarea and i store it in mysql. 
some special below when i up to mysql and load it to my area working well

```
!@#$%^&*()_+-=~<>?{}[]|*-+/:;.,"`
```

(enter) character done with upload to mysql but not to reload. I try to reload with

```
str_replace("\n", "\\n",$string);
```

and it working well

**When i up to mysql some special below characters not working**

```
\'
```

**I try typing double character above it work for upload to mysql but not to reload**

```
typing '' to mysql ' but i want typing ' to mysql '
```

How can i work with some error charactor above (up and reload) with best way. thanks

**Update my way** 
When i up to mysql i using

```
addslashes($string)
```

and when i reload i using

```
 str_replace("\n", "\\n",addslashes($string))
```

It's done with my case thanks all

Comment: Show your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) with ENT_QUOTES

Also, "\n" is a one char. You have to replace it with your code. But also you must do back convert when saving.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

might work but subject to mysql escaping, so a possibly better solution

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

```
/.htaccess
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
```

will prevent php auto-adding the slashes, you can then add them in sql with

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

in your sql statement

and removing them upon read [for textbox] with

```
stripslashes()
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

to display in a DIV you'd have to htmlentities() as explained above

Comment: Do not tell about mysql_* anything.

Comment: @sectus his question was mysql related: `some special below when i up to mysql and load it to my area working` simply addressing the entities part / escaping is a very lazy approach. tell him how they get there in the 1st place, he can then figure out how best to proceed understanding how the entire process.

Comment: @freestyle magic_quotes are nice/easy for most cases, but can be problematic in certain cases.

Comment: Mysql server, but not the mysql extension.